# Php regexp for escaping characters

Tags: php, regex, escaping

I have a string that the user may split manually using comma's.

For example, the string `value1,value2,value3` should result in the array:

`["value1", "value2", "value3"]`

Now what if the user wishes to allow a comma as a substring? I would like to solve that problem by letting the user escape a comma using two comma's or a backslash. For example, the string

"Hi, Stackoverflow" would be written as "Hi,, Stackoverflow" or "Hi\, Stackoverflow".

I find it difficult to evaluate such a string however. I have attempted preg splitting, but there is no way to see if a lookbehind or lookahead series of characters consists of an even or odd number. Furthermore, backslashes and double comma's meant for escaping must be removed as well, which probably requires an additional replace function.

Comment: can you use a different delimiter? Maybe the string can be pipe | delimited?

Comment: The same problem will occur. I do not want to restrict the user of using any characters.

Comment: So I am wondering if you are asking the right question here. How is the data being entered?  Is this through a web form?  Why not have the data entered individually to begin with (i.e. using array access notation if via web form)?

Answer (score 1):

```
$text = 'Hello, World \,asdas, 123';
$data = preg_split('/(?<=[^\\\]),/',$text);
print_r($data);
```

Result

```
Array ( [0] => Hello [1] => World \,asdas [2] => 123 )
```

Comment: To match a backslash, you would need 2 consecutive backslashes in a PHP string, and 4 in a PHP regex string. Secondly, if your string would be Hello World \\,asdas, your function already stopped functioning correctly, because the first backslash should escape the second one, which means the comma should not be escaped for that string.

Comment: You don't wrote before `because the first backslash should escape the second one` ok, will fix this. Give me some time please.

Comment: Oh hang on, that's silly of me. My comment may have been unjust. Of course a user provided backslash should not escape another one. Let me check again. Do you think you can provide the mechanism that allows multiple comma's as escaping mechanism?

Comment: For situation with backslashes before backslashes you could use
    
    `$text = 'Hello, World \\,asdas, 123';`
    `$text = preg_replace('/(\\\\\\\\)+/','\\',$text);`
    `$data = preg_split('/(?<=[^\\\]),/',$text);`
    `print_r($data);`

Also you could use 3 \ inside `[]` instead if 4 \

Answer (score 0):

For this I would run `preg_replace_callback` which allows you to count escape characters used and determine what to do with them. If it turns out that coma is not escaped, replace it to some non-printable character that should not be used by user in his input and then explode by this character:

```php
<?php

$str = "One,Two\\, Two\\\\,Three";
$delimiter = chr(0x0B); // vertical tab, hope you do not expect it in the input?


$escaped = preg_replace_callback('/(\\\\)*,?/', function($m) use($delimiter){
    if(!isset($m[1]) || strlen($m[0])%2) {
        return str_replace(',',$delimiter,preg_replace('/\\\\{2}/','\\',$m[0])); 
    } else {
        return str_replace('\\,',',', preg_replace('/\\\\{2}/','\\',$m[0]));
    }
}, $str);
$array = explode($delimiter, $escaped);
```